# HTML how to group options in a select without using the <optgroup> tag

Tags: html, label, html-select

I have a select dropdown with many options, and they need to be grouped, because I am giving each `<optgroup>` a class and setting them to `display:none`, so that when I select something in another select dropdown for them to become visible. My problem is that I seem to HAVE to use a label, and I really do not want a label. My options list is going to be so long so to insert a class inside each option is going to be a problem, especially with my using Jquery to manipulate them. How can I group them instead? I just can't find a solution anywhere.

HTML example:

```
<select>
<option>Select something</option>
<optgroup class="default" label="defaultLabelNotwanted">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup class="one" style="display:none" label="firstLabelNotWanted">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
    <option>Option4</option>
    <option>Option5</option>
    <option>Option6</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup class="two" style="display:none" label="secondLabelNotWanted">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
    <option>Option4</option>
    <option>Option5</option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option6</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup class="three" style="display:none" label="thirdLabelNotWanted">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
    <option>Option4</option>
    <option>Option5</option>
    <option>Option6</option>
    <option>Option7</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup class="four" style="display:none" label="fourthLabelNotWanted">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
    <option>Option4</option>
    <option>Option5</option>
    <option>Option6</option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: eh?  what is happening, what did you want to happen instead, what have you tried (code)?

Comment: @thebjorn, I want to group my `options` without using the `optgroup` tag (which groups options), but they have to have a `label`. So I want to find out if there is another way to group them, as it seems that you HAVE to use a `label` element when using `optgroup` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only permissible tags inside a `<select>` are `<option>` and `<optgroup>` (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element), so no, there is no other way to group your options other than using an optgroup.

What you can do is move the class from the optgroup to its options, then move all the options directly under the select, and finally remove the optgroups.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const select = $('select');
    select.find('option').each(function () {
        select.append($(this).addClass($(this).parent().attr('class')));
    });
    select.find('optgroup').remove();
});
```

you can then hide options based on class:

```
select.find('.two').hide();
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ux2m6bhw/1/

Comment: This could work - except the `display:none` does not affect it, but I can find a work around it :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide only label?
Did you try this code?

```
optgroup {
  visibility: hidden;
}
optgroup option {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: No it does not work. Is there another way to group them?

Answer (score -1):

If you have control over how your select and it's options are generated then another approach similar to the previous answer would be to just dump all the options into one select (no groups at all) as per below

```
<select>
    <option class="initialitem">Select something</option>
    <option class="zero">Option1</option>
    <option class="zero">Option2</option>
    <option class="zero">Option3</option>
    <option class="one">i Option1</option>
    <option class="one">i Option2</option>
    <option class="one">i Option3</option>
    <option class="one">i Option4</option>
    <option class="one">i Option5</option>
    <option class="one">i Option6</option>
    <option class="two">ii Option1</option>
    <option class="two">ii Option2</option>
    <option class="two">ii Option3</option>
    <option class="two">ii Option4</option>
    <option class="two">ii Option5</option>
    <option class="two">ii Option1</option>
    <option class="two">ii Option6</option>
    <option class="three">iii Option1</option>
    <option class="three">iii Option2</option>
    <option class="three">iii Option3</option>
    <option class="three">iii Option4</option>
    <option class="three">iii Option5</option>
    <option class="three">iii Option6</option>
    <option class="three">iii Option7</option>
    <option class="four">Option1</option>
    <option class="four">Option2</option>
    <option class="four">Option3</option>
    <option class="four">Option4</option>
    <option class="four">Option5</option>
    <option class="four">Option6</option>
</select>
```

Then with JQuery you can hide all options with following statement

```
$('select').find('option').hide();
```

Then to show just a single set do the following

```
$('select').find('.three').show();
$('select').find('.initialitem').show();
```

The above would just show options which have the class of `three`

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I wonder why this has been down voted, but I will give this a go